# Is it possible to use UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight between two Tables in a view, instead of two UIViews?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I am aware how to use the above to transition between two UIViews - but if I have a table in a UIView, and I want to replace it with another Table, can I transition just the two tables, without having to transition the entire view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can transition between the two views. Or, you can make your transition and while doing so bring the second Table to the front by using [self bringSubviewToFront:(tableView)]; Then when you want to transition back, just bring the first tableView to the front.

Comment: Okay, so I have a mainView, with two UITableViews: tocTableView and bmTableView - when I do: [mainView bringSubviewToFront:tocTableView] - I expect just the table view (which occupies the bottom half of the screen) to flip around, but the entire screen flips around??

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. Have you tried it yet?

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` and `UIView`, so you will be able to use CoreAnimation on it.